# Can removing certain IO shield tabs cause enough EMI to disrupt WiFi signals?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-connection, desktop-computer, interference

When I built my PC, I ended up taking off a few tabs on the IO shield, but left the majority of them on. Recently, I've grown concerned about the EMI that could be coming from my PC, as the WiFi in my house has had poor connectivity and I'm not sure if that could be caused by EMI from my PC. Should I be concerned about this? If yes, is there a way to reduce EMI?

Comment: you reduce EMI by using EMI-Shielding. why did you remove it in the first place? The poor connectivity issue is most likeley a neighboring router has been installed recently on the same channel your router is using. While i don't doubt There are some EMI Concerns from removing the shielding, **its probably nowhere near the frequencies of 2.4Ghz or 5.8Ghz WiFi**.

Comment: First consider that you can buy PC cases with a big plastic window in the side. So much for EMI shielding. A little hole doesn't seem so bad anymore. You have to consider that microwave ovens, other 802.11 wifi users especially using partially overlapping channels, bluetooth, wireless baby monitors, security cameras and such are major sources of interference on 2.4GHz. It is so congested that what used to work reliably 40 meters away now has to be 15 meters away.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, holes in your PC's EMI shielding can let EMI leak out. This can be enough to interfere with your PC's Wi-Fi reception and any devices within half a meter or so. It probably wouldn't be enough to cause a problem for a whole house, unless the only Wi-Fi AP sits right next to the leaky PC.

The way to fix it is to replace the missing shield slot covers. They're standard and cheap. Most people that work with desktop PCs probably have a handful sitting in a drawer.

Comment: The Wi-Fi is bad throughout our entire house, which is why I'm not sure if my PC's EMI is the cause of it. But thank you for the information! Where can I get an IO shield for my motherboard? I have an ASRock Z390 Pro4.